# Do python decorators strictly implement the decorator pattern ?

Tags: python, design-patterns, decorator

I've attended a session about decorator pattern where most of the examples provided were in java.For instance in the example below the Pizza object is being decorated with Two toppings .

```
Pizza vegPizza = new ToppingsType1(new ToppingType2(new Pizza()))
```

In python i've seen decorators being used in the scenarios like this

```
@applyTopping2
@applyTopping1
makePizza():
    pass
```

Though here I can see that the the makePizza function is being decorated with two functions , but it differs a lot from the class based approach of java.
My question is do python decorators strictly implement the decorator pattern or do the implementation is a little different but the idea is same.

PS: I am not sure where to lookup the standard definition of the decorator pattern.though wikipedia gives an example in a dynamic language (JS) but my question still holds good :)

Comment: Nothing prevents Python decorators from being classes as well.

Comment: *Strictly implementing the decorator patter*? Is there a standard definition of how a decorator should look like?

Comment: I think the burden is upon you on getting a definition of what would be a "strict decorator pattern". (then, we Python fans can proceed on describe why the strictness is irrelevant and defend Python approach  :-) )

Comment: @jsbueno this is funny because it's really true. Anyway, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators/1594484#1594484 . It's an example of how the decorators work in Python. You will see if it match your expectation of the design patter.

Comment: I too was secretly hoping that somebody would come and defend the python approach but sadly the python wiki says they are diff ;(, any way i don't care , decorator pattern is good to know but i am gonna use python decorators only for now :) :)

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article on [Python decorators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators): "Despite the name, Python decorators are not an implementation of the decorator pattern".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [read this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators#What_is_a_Python_Decorator) which explains what are python's decorators.

> The "decorators" we talk about with concern to Python are not exactly the same thing as the [DecoratorPattern](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DecoratorPattern) [...]. A Python decorator is a specific change to the Python syntax that allows us to more conveniently alter functions and methods (and possibly classes in a future version). This supports more readable applications of the [DecoratorPattern](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DecoratorPattern) but also other uses as well.

So, you will be able to implement the "classical" decorator pattern with python's decorator, but you will be able to do much more (funny ;)) things with those decorators.

In your case, it could looks like :

```
def applyTopping1(functor):
    def wrapped():
        base_pizza = functor()
        base_pizza.add("mozzarella")
        return base_pizza
    return wrapped

def applyTopping2(functor):
    def wrapped():
        base_pizza = functor()
        base_pizza.add("ham")
        return base_pizza
    return wrapped
```

And then you will get a Margherita :)

Answer (score 1):

not a real answer, just a fun example on how one can do things in Python - compared to static languages:

```
def pizza_topping_decorator_factory(topping):
    def fresh_topping_decorator(pizza_function):
        def pizza_with_extra_topping(*args, **kw):
            return pizza_function(*args, **kw) + ", " + topping
        return pizza_with_extra_topping
    return fresh_topping_decorator


mozzarela = pizza_topping_decorator_factory("mozarella")
anchove = pizza_topping_decorator_factory("anchove")

@anchove
@mozzarela
def pizza():
    return "Pizza"
```

When pasting this code on the Python console:

```
>>> 
>>> print pizza()
Pizza, mozarella, anchove
```

Comment: It is better not to use `_decorator_factory` suffix in real code to improve readability.

Comment: @lig - shure - most names here are just part of the fun in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

The `@decorator` syntax in Python is nothing more than syntax sugar.

The code

```
@decorator
def foo():
    pass
```

is nothing more than

```
def foo():
    pass

foo = decorator(foo)
```

The final result just depends on what do you want for it to be.

You may use class as `decorator` and will get object instantiated from this class with `foo` as `__init__` arg.

You may use object instantiated with some parameters as decorator like in code bellow

```
class Decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        pass

    def __call__(self, foo):
        return foo()

@Decorator(arg1_value, arg2_value)
def foo():
    pass
```

This is only you who decides what your code will look like and what it will do not any pattern or somebody from java world:)

Comment: If one follows this logic, than the "class" keyword is just "syntax sugar" in Python, for `Decorator = type("Decorator", (object,), dict(__init__=lambda s, foo: setattr(s,"f", foo), __call__=lambda s: s.f()))`

Comment: but like with function we get an object of the called function here we don't